# How I can remove access view from a page layout?

Tags: page-layout, access

I have this page layout where the user "A" it's able to see the fields

1. Name,
2. LastName and
3. Email

but User "B" should not be able to see the field `Email`

I try to do it by the perm set but the 2 users use the same perm set.

Comment: Do they have the same profile?

Comment: yes they have the same profile, but removing the object permission via profile its not a opcion, the profile should stay without access to any object or field.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you would go about this by setting up the profile with the least amount of access and extending users a’s access via permission sets or a separate profile. Not sure it meets the requirements but I believe you could also conditionally display the email field in the lightning page if you’re using lightning

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5

Comment: lightning page is not an option